# O que fazer quando o looping se repete em 2 areas diferentes

Tags: javascript

O código pega os valores dos `inputs` e envia para o `textarea` porém quando adicionado mais de um `titulo` os valores se repetem no resultado dos titulos, por exemplo, as descrições do titulo 1 é são as mesmas do titulo 2 vice e versa, porque isso acontece? e como fazer que funcione sem alterar o proposito?

> Executar o código no [codepen.io](https://codepen.io/jonyboy/pen/KBjRxX) ou [jsfiddle.net](https://jsfiddle.net/jonyboy/pvkare9w/)

**O que acontece:**
[image: ERRADO]
**O que deveria acontecer:**
[image: CERTO]

```js
function resultado() {
  var inp2 = document.getElementsByName("inp2");
  var titu = document.getElementsByName("titu");
  var res = document.getElementById("resultado");
  res.value = "";
  
if (titu[0]) {
  for (var k = 0; k < titu.length; k++) {
    if (titu[k].value.trim() != '') {
      res.value += `<div>
<span>${titu[k].value.trim()}</span>
</div>
<ul>\n`;
      for (var j = 0; j < inp2.length; j++) {
        if (inp2[j].value.trim() != '') {
          res.value += `<li>${inp2[j].value.trim()}</li>\n`;
        }
      }
    }
  }
}else {
  console.log("error")
  res.value += `<ul>\n`;
    for (var l = 0; l < inp2.length; l++) {
      if (inp2[l].value.trim() != '') {
        res.value += `<li>${inp2[l].value.trim()}</li>\n`;
      }
    }
 }
};

// -----------------------------------------

let cont2 = 1;
document.getElementById("add2").onclick = function clone2() {
  let container2 = document.getElementById("saida2");  
  let tempLinha2 = document.querySelector('#template2'); 
  let clonar2 = document.importNode(tempLinha2.content, true); 
  
  const label2 = clonar2.querySelector("label");
  label2.htmlFor = cont2;
  clonar2.querySelector("input").className = cont2;
  
  container2.appendChild(clonar2);
  cont2++;
};
document.getElementById("del2").onclick = function del2() {
    document.querySelector('#saida2 #linha2:last-child').remove();
};

// ---------------------------------------

let cont3 = 1;
document.getElementById("addtit").onclick = function clone3() {
  let container3 = document.getElementById("saida2");  
  let tempLinha3 = document.querySelector('#template3');
  let clonar3 = document.importNode(tempLinha3.content, true); 
  
  const label3 = clonar3.querySelector("label");
  label3.htmlFor = cont3;
  clonar3.querySelector("input").className = cont3;
  
  container3.appendChild(clonar3);
  cont3++;
  document.getElementById('add2').id = 'add3';
  document.getElementById('del2').id = 'del3';
};
document.getElementById("deltit").onclick = function deltit() {
    document.querySelector('#saida2 #alg:last-child').remove();
    document.getElementById('add3').id = 'add2';
    document.getElementById('del3').id = 'del2';
};

// -----------------------------------------
if (document.getElementById("add3")) {
let cont4 = 1;
document.getElementById("add3").onclick = function clone4() {
  let container4 = document.getElementById("saida3");  
  let tempLinha4 = document.querySelector('#template2');
  let clonar4 = document.importNode(tempLinha4.content, true); 
  
  const label4 = clonar4.querySelector("label");
  label4.htmlFor = cont4;
  clonar4.querySelector("input").className = cont4;
  
  container4.appendChild(clonar4);
  cont4++;
};
document.getElementById("del3").onclick = function del4() {
  document.querySelector('#saida3 #linha2:last-child').remove();
};
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
<button id="addtit">+ TITULO</button>
<button id="deltit">- TITULO</button>
<button id="add2">+ DESCRIÇÃO</button>
<button id="del2">- DESCRIÇÃO</button>
<div id="saida2"></div>
<div class='botoes'>
<button onclick="resultado()" id='concluir'>CONCLUIR</button>
</div>
<div class="header"><span class="titulo">RESULTADO</span>
</div>
<div class="linha"><textarea id="resultado"></textarea>
</div>
</div>
  

<!-- template 2 -->
<template id="template2">
<div class="linha" id="linha2"><div class="coluna1"><label for="0">DESCRIÇÃO:</label></div><div class="coluna2"><input name="inp2" class="0" type="text"/></div>
</div>
</template>
<!-- template 3 -->
<template id="template3">
<div id="alg">
<div class="linha"><div class="coluna1"><label for="0">TITULO:</label></div><div class="coluna2"><input name="titu" class="0" type="text"/></div>
</div>
<div class="linha" id="linha3"><div class="coluna1"><label for="0">DESCRIÇÃO:</label></div><div class="coluna2"><input name="inp2" class="0" type="text"/></div>
</div>
<div id="saida3"></div>
</div>
</template>
```

Comment: Pelos testes, os inputs ficam sempre com os mesmo name, na verdade, cada input deveria ter um id diferente, assim você pdoeria pegar os valores de cada

Comment: Sim, mas como cada `id` deve ser unico, como fazer para passar de `name` para `id` e manter o `loop`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você precisa organizar os seus inputs, segue um exemplo

```js
var titulos = []
var divTitulos = document.getElementById("titulos")
var tmplTitulo = document.getElementById("tmplTitulo").content
var tmplDescricao = document.getElementById("tmplDescricao").content

var btAddTitulo = document.getElementById("addTitulo")
var btDelTitulo = document.getElementById("delTitulo")
var btAddDescricao = document.getElementById("addDescricao")
var btDelDescricao = document.getElementById("delDescricao")
var btConcluir = document.getElementById("concluir")
var txtSaida = document.getElementById("saida")

var addTitulo = function () {
  var wrapper = document.importNode(tmplTitulo, true)
  divTitulos.appendChild(wrapper)
  wrapper = divTitulos.children[divTitulos.children.length - 1]
  
  var titulo = {
    wrapper: wrapper,
    input: wrapper.querySelector('.titulo'),
    delTitulo: wrapper.querySelector('.delTitulo'),
    addDescricao: wrapper.querySelector('.addDescricao'),
    divDescricoes: wrapper.querySelector('.descricoes'),
    descricoes: []
  }
  
  titulo.delTitulo.addEventListener('click', delTitulo.bind(titulo))
  titulo.addDescricao.addEventListener('click', addDescricao.bind(titulo))  
  titulos.push(titulo)
}

var delTitulo = function () {
  this.wrapper.remove()
  var index = titulos.indexOf(this)
  titulos.splice(index, 1);
}

var addDescricao = function () {
  var wrapper = document.importNode(tmplDescricao, true)
  this.divDescricoes.appendChild(wrapper)
  wrapper = this.divDescricoes.children[this.divDescricoes.children.length - 1]
  
  var descricao = {
    titulo: this,
    wrapper: wrapper,
    input: wrapper.querySelector('.descricao'),
    delDescricao: wrapper.querySelector('.delDescricao')
  }
  
  descricao.delDescricao.addEventListener('click', delDescricao.bind(descricao))  
  this.descricoes.push(descricao)
}

var delDescricao = function () {
  this.wrapper.remove()
  var index = this.titulo.descricoes.indexOf(this)
  this.titulo.descricoes.splice(index, 1);
}

var concluir = function () {
  var html = '<div>';
  titulos.forEach(function (titulo) {
    html += `
  <div>
    <span>${titulo.input.value}</span>
  </div>
  <ul>`;
    titulo.descricoes.forEach(function (descricao) {
      html += `    
    <li>${descricao.input.value}</li>`
    })
  html += `
  </ul>
`
  })
  html += `</div>`
  txtSaida.value = html
}

btAddTitulo.addEventListener("click", addTitulo)
btConcluir.addEventListener("click", concluir)
```

```css
.acoes {
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}

.descricoes > div {
  margin-top: 5px;
}

#saida {
  margin-top: 5px;
  width: 500px;
  height: 200px;
}
```

```html
<template id="tmplTitulo">
  <fieldset>
    <legend>Conteudo</legend>
    <div class="acoes">
      <input class="delTitulo" type="button" value="Remover Titulo" />
      <input class="addDescricao" type="button" value="Adicionar Descrição" />
    </div>
    <div>
      <label>
        Titulo
        <input type="text" class="titulo" />
      </label>  
    </div>
    <div class="descricoes">
    </div>
  </fieldset>
</template>

<template id="tmplDescricao">
  <div>
    <label>
      Descrição
      <input type="text" class="descricao" />
    </label>  
    <input class="delDescricao" type="button" value="Remover Descrição" />
  </div>
</template>

<div>
  <div id="acoes">
    <input id="addTitulo" type="button" value="Adicionar Titulo" />
    <input id="concluir" type="button" value="Concluir" />
  </div>
  <div id="titulos">
  </div>
  <div>
    <textarea id="saida" readonly></textarea>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Eu dei a recompensa para a resposta errada e agora o que eu faço?

Answer (score 0):

O problem está nessa parte do código:

```
if (titu[0]) {
  for (var k = 0; k < titu.length; k++) {
    if (titu[k].value.trim() != '') {
      res.value += `<div>
<span>${titu[k].value.trim()}</span>
</div>
<ul>\n`;
      for (var j = 0; j < inp2.length; j++) {
        if (inp2[j].value.trim() != '') {
          res.value += `<li>${inp2[j].value.trim()}</li>\n`;
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Os titulos e as descrições tem o mesmo nome `titu` e `inp2` e você esta criando um looping para cada e acaba resultando no que está na primeira imagem.
Você pode mudar seu código e colocar nomes e ids diferentes.
Mas se você não quer mudar seu código, você deve usar um loop para ambos, como este código aqui:

```js
if (titu[0]) {
  for (var k = 0; k < titu.length; k++) {
    if (titu[k].value.trim() != '') {
      res.value += `<div>
<span>${titu[k].value.trim()}</span>
</div>
<ul>\n`;
        if (inp2[k].value.trim() != '') {
         res.value += `<li>${inp2[k].value.trim()}</li>\n`;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Só funciona se for com uma descrição, se adicionar mais de uma as outras não funcionam.